# Windows 10 runas escaping

Tags: cmd, escaping, windows-10, runas

This is more of theoretical construct, or an interesting problem, rather than a real world scenario - in which case I would use a batch file to prevent escaping problems.

1. Let's say we want to run runas on Windows 10 in a way:

   ```
   runas /user:John "cmd.exe /k echo %path%"
   ```

   this does not work because %path% is expanded and we get error:

   Attempting to start cmd.exe /k echo C:\Program Files (x...
     ...
     RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - cmd.exe /k ech...
     ...
     1734: The array bounds are invalid.

   Is it possible to solve this? I.e. how to escape %?
   If we try

   ```
   runas /user:John "cmd.exe /k echo ^%path^%"
   ```

   the output in the new shell window is just

   ```
   %path%
   ```

   which is not what we want (we want the value of the PATH variable to be printed to the console).
2. Let's say we want some other thing and we need to use " in our command:

   ```
   runas /user:John "cmd.exe /k dir c:\Program Files"
   ```

   This does not work - obviously because the space between Program and Files, the new shell window that appears says twice "File Not Found".

   One would expect that the solution for this would be

   ```
   runas /user:John "cmd.exe /k dir ^"c:\Program Files^""
   ```

   But that does not work (runas prints usage help). The question is why?

   The real solution here is using `\"`:

   ```
   runas /user:John "cmd.exe /k dir \"c:\Program Files\""
   ```

   This escaping can be seen in runas usage help Examples section. But this is not a common way for escaping quotes, is it? The question here - why `^"` does not work?

Comment: of course `runas .... set path` is a cheating way to get it to display the path in the new window :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have three entities involved:

- the outer `cmd` shell, in which you are typing `runas ...`
- `runas.exe`, which gets the creds, starts a new process, etc.
- the inner `cmd` shell, which is what `runas` was told to execute

When you type `runas ... "cmd.exe /k echo %path%"`

- the outer shell sees `%path%` and expands it
- `runas` takes the expanded command, starts the inner shell with that as arguments
- the inner shell echos what it saw

When you type `runas ... "cmd.exe /k echo ^%path^%"`

- the outer shell sees `^%path^%` *in quotes*, and interprets the carets as escaping the percent signs, so it doesn't expand `path` *and leaves the carets in place*
- `runas` sees the command to be run as `cmd.exe /k echo %^path^%`
- the inner shell sees `echo ^%path^%` and you see `%path%` in the new window.

So when the carets are inside quotes, they are retained. But if no quotes are used, `runas` won't work -- the command must be seen as a single parameter.  What to do?

One way is to use a batch file, like you said.

Another is to use a different environment variable:

```
set aa=echo ^%path^%
runas /user:rpres "cmd.exe /k %aa%"
```

- The outer shell sees the carets *not in quotes* in the `set` command, and produces a variable with the value `echo %path%`
- The outer shell sees a variable to be expanded on the `runas` line, and expands it. ONCE. The inner `%path%` is not expanded
- runas sees the command as `cmd.exe /k echo %path%` and runas that
- the inner shell sees `echo %path%`. It expands the path. You see the expanded path in the new window.

A final way to do it is to get OUT of the quotes before escaping the carets: `runas.exe ... "cmd.exe /k echo "^%path^%`
It is important that there be no spaces that are not in quotes, though!

- The outer shell sees the carets *not in quotes* on the `runas` line, and escapes the percent signs while removing the carets.
- runas sees the command as `cmd.exe /k echo %path%` and runas that
- the inner shell sees `echo %path%`. It expands the path. You see the expanded path in the new window.

Note that you can "get back in the quotes" after finishing the escaped percents. e.g. `runas /user:rpres "cmd.exe /k echo here is my path :::"^%path^%":::"` will display `here is my path` followed by the path enclosed in three colon signs.

Comment: This trick with ending the quoted part and having `^%path^%` outside the quoted argument, but without spaces, just works! Very nice. So this answers 1. Would you be able to provide answer for 2. too?

Comment: 2 matches my second scenario. The shell sees carets in quotes and therefore doesn't expand them, but leaves them intact. If you want to do it with carets, you have to get out of the quotes, add a careted quote, then get back into quotes, then get out of the quotes again and finish with a careted quote: `runas /user:rpres "cmd.exe /k dir "^""c:\program files"^"`

Comment: Much easier to accept `runas`'s suggestion and use backslashes